# How can i read http response of a complete page including all web elements in watir?I need the data of Headers

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

[image]

I need the  data of the headers and the response code.

Comment: There is some useful information here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755480/how-to-capture-all-requests-made-by-page-in-webdriver-is-there-any-alternative

Answer (score 1):

Watir is powered by Selenium WebDriver, which doesn't have a proxy built-in to do this sort of thing. A few suggestions are made over on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813872/how-to-capture-http-full-headers-with-watir). In the past (working in C#) I was able to use the Fiddler core proxy to inspect traffic after making a response.